# Bash command line suffix macro

Tags: bash, shell, macros

Is it possible to create a custom bash macro that works on suffixes (similar to the `&`) ?

Example: Let `XX` be a custom "suffix macro". Then `cp file /tmp XX` would execute the macro associated with XX.

Goal: I would want to create a macro that switches to the last argument, so that I could for example copy a file an directly jump into the folder where I copied it into. (I know that I could do a "cpd" alias or something that achieves this, but I'm wondering if there is a way to create macros as I described them).

Comment: `!$` is a shortcut for the last word of the last command you typed. So you can do `cp fred /tmp` followed by `cd !$` to go to /tmp

Comment: `&` is not a macro; it's a shell metacharacter with a hard-coded meaning to the shell--it's one of three characters, along with `;` and `<newline`>, that can terminate a command list. That said, `bash` does not allow you to define such constructs. Global aliases in `zsh` are similar, however.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually it's $_

Comment: @David - you can try this: $ echo a b c; echo $! - !$ - $_
echo a b c; echo $! - $! - $_
a b c
- - c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using $_ in Bash (it's not a macro though) but if you just need it for copying a file and then move to the copied folder then do something like I have shown after "OR"

```
$ echo a b c; echo $! - !$ - $_
echo a b c; echo $! - $! - $_
a b c
- - c
```

OR

```
$ pwd
/home/c10001/giga

$ ls -l rerun.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c10001 Domain Users 76 Jul 22 13:25 rerun.sh


$ ls -ld test; ls -l test
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jul 17 12:23 test
total 0

drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jul 17 12:23 java
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jul 17 12:23 resources


$ cp rerun.sh 1; cd $_; pwd; ls -l rerun.sh

/home/c10001/giga/1

-rwxr-xr-x 1 c10001 Domain Users 76 Jul 24 09:41 rerun.sh
```

Now, if you really want a MACRO kind of feature, you can try playing with "eval" in BASH (hint).
i.e. NOTE: $_ is set to the last argument passed of the last command.

```
$ pwd
/home/c10001/giga

$ cp rerun.sh 1; echo $_; XX=";cd $_";
1

$ echo $XX
;cd 1

$ eval cp rerun.sh 1 $XX

$ pwd
/home/c10001/giga/1
```

As you see, I ran eval to process $XX during copying rerun.sh to folder 1 and because XX was set to "; cd $_", it expanded its value and cd to that folder already. Using ";" for setting XX is required to separate the cp command with cd command during the above *eval* line.

This will also work, if XX is set to "; cd $_" and where XX now becomes "; cd 1" (i.e. you did "cp rerun.sh 1") but later if you'll run "eval cp rerun.sh 2 $XX" i.e. copying rerun.sh to a different folder this time, which is folder **2** and once eval ... is done, you'll be in /home/c10001/giga/2 folder.

Comment: Thanks. This does not exactly solve the problem, but it is probably as good as it gets.